# context hierarchy of book

Tags: data-warehouse, olap

I have book dimension for the bookstore with `ISBN, title, author, publication year, publisher company` attributes. For time, it is easy to see hierachy but for the book dimension, I could not manage to construct the hierarchy. What is the context hierarchy for the book dimesnion ? Can you help me because I am abit confused about how to construct it ?

EDIT: as an example, for time

```
           date < week of the day < month < year
           date < week of the day < year

 as an example, for calendar

           Calendar Year > Calendar Quarter > Calendar Month > Day
```

Comment: IF there is a unclear part, feel free to ask OR say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every dimension needs to have a hierarchy. Dates do have an obvious natural hierarchy (e.g. century-year-month-day) but there is no reason that books 'must' have one.

If there is a hierarchy, it will be based on whatever information is useful to your report users and is available in your source data. For librarians, the [Dewey Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification) or [Library of Congress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress_Classification) classifications might be good hierarchies, but for a bookstore they might be completely irrelevant.

You need to find out from your users how they expect to drill down into book details and model the dimension accordingly. Perhaps your company already has an in-house classification system or perhaps there simply is no hierarchy, just a collection of attributes that are used in reports.

Asking for opinions here is unlikely to help because I could say `Author->PublicationYear->Book` but your users might say `Author->Book` or `PublicationYear->Publisher->Author->Book` or something completely different.

Comment: assume -> IF my expectation is, drill down, based on the title and author, what should be expected hierarchy ?

Comment: The point of my answer was that you should ask the people who will use your reports; my opinion is useless here. I could say `Author->PublicationYear->Book` but your users might say `Author->Book` or `PublicationYear->Publisher->Author->Book` or something completely different.

Comment: I undestand. Can you also add this comment to the your answer? Thanks

Comment: Sure, I've added the example I gave